# OUTPUT clause with window functions

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, output-clause

**Is there an undocumented restriction in the `OUTPUT` clause, or is this a bug?**

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (SomeId int, flag bit, value int);
```

I would like to use a calculated value in an `UPDATE` statement, and then use `OUTPUT` to output the value. Note that the calculated value is not being used in the `SET` part, which might have allowed a workaround by outputting the left-hand-side column.

The following works fine, it is a perfectly standard updatable subquery (derived table).

```
UPDATE subT1
SET flag = 1
OUTPUT inserted.SomeValue
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      SomeValue = t1.value + 123
    FROM t1
) subT1;
```

However using a window function gets a weird error:

```
UPDATE subT1
SET flag = 1
OUTPUT inserted.Sum
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Sum = SUM(t1.value) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.SomeId)
    FROM t1
) subT1;
```

```
Msg 404 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
The column reference "inserted.Sum" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.
```

Which doesn't make sense as we already established that calculated columns can be referred to using `inserted`.

OK let's try using `OUTPUT subT1.Sum` anyway, rather than `inserted.Sum`:

```
Msg 4104 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
The multi-part identifier "subT1.Sum" could not be bound.
```

which makes sense, since that table reference has been modified, and the docs say:

> If the table being modified is also specified in the FROM clause, any reference to columns in that table must be qualified with the INSERTED or DELETED prefix.

---

Meanwhile, if I use a join on a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (SomeId int, flag bit, value int);
```

it works fine

```
UPDATE t1
SET flag = 1
OUTPUT subT2.Sum
FROM t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t2.*,
      Sum = SUM(t2.value) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.SomeId)
    FROM t2
) subT2 ON subT2.SomeId = t1.SomeId;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6UyJLSFX)

**So is the fact that a window function throws that error a bug, or an undocumented restriction?**

Having said all that, a join *inside* a subquery is also not allowed, so most likely it is an undocumented restriction.

```
UPDATE subT1
SET flag = 1
OUTPUT inserted.Sum
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
      Sum = t2.value
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON t2.SomeId = t1.SomeId
) subT1;
```

```
Msg 404 Level 16 State 1 Line 3
The column reference "inserted.Sum" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.
```

Comment: Perhaps the fact that the error message is exactly the same as the one in your last example, where the calculated column *actually* references a different table's column, hints at the way window functions are implemented internally. I mean maybe on some very low level they are indeed represented as a separate rowset from the table they are applied to, even though syntactically nothing suggests that. Not that this would be helpful as an answer without official confirmation, even if it was true. Such an interesting discovery, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yes, it appears that might be the case, but that might be a bug. That last example with the join is *also* undocumented, so I'm still none the wiser.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this explicitly covered in the documentation but `OUTPUT deleted.Sum` [does work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811957/73226).

This does make some sense though as the `SUM` is calculated on the values "pre-update" rather than "post-update"

i.e. the below returns a `SUM` of `2` rather than `0`

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (SomeId int, flag bit, value int);

INSERT T1 values (1,1,1), (1,1,1);

UPDATE subT1
SET flag = 1, value = 0
OUTPUT deleted.Sum AS [SUM(value)],
       deleted.value AS [deleted.value], 
       inserted.value AS [inserted.value]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Sum = SUM(t1.value) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.SomeId)
    FROM t1
) subT1;

DROP TABLE t1
```

| SUM(value) | deleted.value | inserted.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/UhClRrD4)

For the simpler expression of `SomeValue = t1.value + 123` it is able to calculate `inserted.SomeValue` distinct from `deleted.SomeValue` by adding a compute scalar on the output stream but presumably window functions would be too complex to do this too.

i.e. the below ...

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (SomeId int, flag bit, value int);

INSERT T1 values (1,1,1), (1,1,1);

UPDATE subT1
SET flag = 1, 
     value = 999
OUTPUT deleted.SomeValue AS [deleted.SomeValue],
       inserted.SomeValue AS [inserted.SomeValue]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      SomeValue = t1.value + 123
    FROM t1
) subT1;

DROP TABLE t1
```

Returns

| deleted.SomeValue | inserted.SomeValue |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | 1122 |
| 124 | 1122 |

And the execution plan is the same as

```
UPDATE t1
SET flag = 1, 
     value = 999
OUTPUT deleted.value  + 123 AS [deleted.SomeValue],
       inserted.value  + 123 AS [inserted.SomeValue]
FROM t1;
```

Comment: How interesting, didn't think of using `deleted`. Doesn't explain why the first example `OUTPUT inserted.SomeValue` works then (I would have thought it's a parsing-level error in the syntax, rather than a runtime error, so Compute Scalar optimizations should be irrelevant), and it does seem to be missing from the docs.

Comment: `OUTPUT inserted.SomeValue` is just treated the same as `OUTPUT inserted.value + 123` - which is a valid thing to do. But it wouldn't be valid to do `OUTPUT SUM(inserted.value) OVER (PARTITION BY inserted.SomeId)`

Comment: It's interesting that in the case of `OUTPUT inserted.SomeValue` you don't get the error which is a compile-time parsing error (proven by `sp_describe_first_result_set`) even though the optimization you mention seems like it should need to compile a plan, which only happens at a later stage. There should be no logical reason why a syntax error would depend on compiler optimizations, I can't think of anywhere else this happens. So if anything it sounds as if *that* case is a bug that it doesn't throw an error.